# Identify a space LEGO set from incomplete model

Tags: set-identification, space

Could someone help me find out which sets these are from please?

[image]
https://www.amazon.co.uk/clouddrive/share/manpK0pmTJUynGo8X3P5iBqpYEEIdjnO9Ol2t3dhdNR?v=grid&ref_=cd_ph_share_link_copy

[image]
https://www.amazon.co.uk/clouddrive/share/0d8gUy7oMWYN3Z3XiOYGYe8XJojtyCSzWVYKeEC39hV?v=grid&ref_=cd_ph_share_link_copy

Answer (score 7):

These are

- [6849-1: Satellite Patroller](http://brickset.com/sets/6849-1/Satellite-Patroller)
  [image]
- [6808-1: Galaxy Trekkor](http://brickset.com/sets/6808-1/Galaxy-Trekkor)
  [image]